# Write powershell script right

Tags: powershell

i have problem with my PowerShell script. Its don't work if i use it on task schedule. I try a lot of ways how to fix it, but don't found solution.
my code will be

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

$Username = "test@test.com"
$Password = "test-" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

 Import-PSSession $Session
  
 Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.com -SearchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))" -deletecontent
 Send-MailMessage -From 'test@test.com ' -To 'it.support@support.com ' -Subject 'Test mail'
```

i want delete emails older then 7 month and send letter about it. In console this code works fine

```
 Search-Mailbox -Identity test@test.comm -SearchQuery "(Received:01/12/2017..$((get-date).AddMonths(-7).ToString("MM/dd/yyy")))" -deletecontent
```

So, first off all i need connect, then  `Import-PSSession $Session`
Any idea how to write code correctly ?

Error log
[image]

Comment: what errors do you get? have you tried looking at the output from adding `Start-Transcript` to the top of the script?

Comment: writing (0x1) on task scheduler, i try to write ```Start-Transcript``` , but it not helping ..  txt file is empty

Comment: if the transcript file it empty ... but was created, then the script is _starting_ ... and then apparently hanging or crashing out. ///// i would try running the task as the currently logged on user so that you can see what happens in the PoSh console.

Comment: I add my error log

Comment: Currently your deleting seems to work, however you get the warning that you will need to use another cmdlet in the future as `Search-Mailbox` is retired... The Error you get is about a missing parameter for `Send-MailMessage`.

Comment: So, how i need to change it ? it will be nice if send how much mb was deleted and how much latter left and how much they memory use.

Comment: @mausasu1234 - PLEASE, do not post images of text. see >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question <<<

Comment: @mausasu1234 - there are at least two problems revealed by what little i can read of the blurry error text image you posted ... [A] you are using a cmdlet that MS retired 2020-07. [B] your code shows that you have a required user interaction - the `confirm` dialog. that will - **_of course_** - stop your code.

Comment: Sorry for img, but i can't write it in text because after 1s error window is gone.. i try 5 times to do this img. About everything you say please tell me more, im now in power shell hard to understand everything

Comment: @T-Me can u tell me  "use another cmdlet in the future as Search-Mailbox is retired" i try a lot of change's but nothing work for me, maybe you can write code for me for this situation?